# Update MySQL database using php form using text boxes

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql-update

Hello I have an issue with updating MySQL using PHP form in Netbeans the issue that occurs is: 
"
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: fetched_row in **C:\Xampp\htdocs\Resume_DB\PHP\Edication_Edit.php** on line **75**
"

In all 4 of my text boxes. The code I have is :

```
    <?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("cs266db_db1");


    if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
 {
  $sql_query="SELECT * FROM education Where Edit_Education=".$_GET['edit_id'];
$result_set=  mysql_query($sql_query);
$fetched_row= mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
}

 if(isset($_POST['btn_update']))
 {
//variables for input data
$Class = $_POST['Class'];
$Discipline = $_POST['Discipline'];
$Description = $_POST['Description'];
$Term = $_POST['Term'];


//sql query for update data 
   $sql_query = "UPDATE Education SET Class='$Class',  Discipline='$Discipline', Description='$Description', Term='$Term' WHERE               Education_Edit=".$_GET['edit_id'];



  //sql query execution function

  if(mysql_query($sql_query))
 {
   ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   alert('Data Has Been Updated');
   window.location.href='Eduaction.php';
   </script>
    <?php
 }
 else 
{
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Error Occured while Updating Data');
    </script>
    <?php
 }

  //sql query execution function 
}

  if(isset($_POST['btn-cancel']))
 {
header("Location: Education.php");
 }
  ?>

       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Edit Education</title>

  </head>
  <body>
 <center>

   <div id="header">
    <div id="content">
    <label>Edit Education</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
  <div id="content">
    <form method="post">
     <table align="center">
    <tr>
   **<td><input type="text" name="Class" placeholder="Class" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Class']; ?>" required /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Discipline" placeholder="Discipline" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Discipline']; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Description" placeholder="Description" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Description']; ?>" required /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="Text" name="Term" placeholder="Term" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Term']; ?>" required</td>**
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button type="submit" name="btn-update"><strong>UPDATE</strong></button>
<button type="submit" name="btn-cancel"><strong>Cancel</strong></button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

```
  <div id="footer">
  <div id="content">

  </div>
 </div>

 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help guys

Comment: `fetched_row` is set inside a condition but there is no condition in the `view`..

Comment: Did you try to use mysql_error()? If the condition for isset($_GET['edit_id']) is **true** then should be a mysql error, and you can check it with mysql_error() statement.

Comment: Ok that fixed the error which is great! Thank you Greg. But the SQL wont update still. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that fetched_row is only assigned when $_GET['edit_id'] is set. Otherwise it does not exist, but you're still trying to use it, even if $_GET['edit_id'] is not set.

Change

```
<td><input type="Text" name="Term" placeholder="Term" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Term']; ?>" required</td>**
```

To:

```
<td><input type="Text" name="Term" placeholder="Term" value="<?php echo (isset($fetched_row['Term']))? $fetched_row['Term'] : ''; ?>" required</td>**
```

Comment: I think it should be `isset($_GET['edit_id'])` irrespective of `isset($fetched_row['Term'])`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue I was getting on the page but the SQL wont update, any idea why?

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm making sure the variable is set, if not set, do nothing. it doesn't matter which you use.

Comment: @DillonBurke Try to echo out the update query and see if it will run as is, this looks more like a syntax issue with the query itself than a problem with the php code(invalid queries are able to be made with perfectly good code). If you're using your alert to tell if it worked, that should never work because it's before even the Document statement. move that logic to the head section of your page to see the alert.

Comment: @Greg Borbonus, I got the update button to work now and Im receiving an alert finally but the error:
Notice: Undefined index: edit_id in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Resume_DB\PHP\Edication_Edit.php on line 24


on line 24 which is:    $sql_query = "UPDATE Education SET Class='$Class',  Discipline='$Discipline', Description='$Description', Term='$Term' WHERE               Education_Edit=".$_GET['edit_id'];

Comment: that's because your IF condition that is checking for post, is outside of your $_GET check, but in either case, it means you're not posting to your script with the ?edit_id=# on the url itself

Answer (score 1):

It seems instead of "Edit_Education" you are using "Education_Edit" in update query or instead of "Education_Edit" you are using "Edit_Education" in select query.

```
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM education Where Edit_Education=".$_GET['edit_id'];

$sql_query = "UPDATE Education SET Class='$Class',  Discipline='$Discipline', Description='$Description', Term='$Term' WHERE Education_Edit=".$_GET['edit_id'];
```

Comment: Please share database table structure

Answer (score 0):

change  if(isset($_POST['btn_update'])) to if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])) because in html button tag you named button as btn-update .
In update query change column name Education_Edit change to Edit_Education